# AWS "amplify push" failed with "Command failed with exit code 1: yarn --production"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was following [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-rest/node-api/q/platform/js) tutorial to add a lambda function in my AWS amplify node.js proejct, when I

```
amplify push
```

It ends up with this error:

```
Current Environment: dev

| Category | Resource name | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Function | mylambda      | Create    | awscloudformation |
| Api      | myapi         | Create    | awscloudformation |
✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Packaging lambda function failed with the error 
Command failed with exit code 1: yarn --production
An error occurred during the push operation: Packaging lambda function failed with the error 
Command failed with exit code 1: yarn --production
```

I tried recreate the amplify project, but ends up with the same error.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

First go to path:

```
/myproject-backend/amplify/backend/function/lambdaName/src
```

Second:

```
npm install
```

Later:

```
amplify push
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. In my case, I had Hadoop yarn installed on my macOS. `yarn` command on my terminal was invoking Hadoop yarn.

I removed(renamed) the `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop` directory to remove the Hadoop. After that, `amplify push` ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with Amplify in Ubuntu (WSL). But the windows system had no such issue. I suspect that it was due to yarn not being installed properly in WSL...as yarn --version shows 0.32+git. I am having trouble with uninstalling yarn in WSL...

A follow-up...I figured out what's happening with the yarn in ubuntu...it was contained in cmdtest package - removed that and yarn was also deleted then amplify pushed successfully